# Problema al crear botón dinámico y asignarle evento

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy creando botones dinámicamente con valores que obtiene al momento de dar clic a un botón, para así poder generar un query con linq hacia un archivo XML.

Se generan con satisfacción dichos botones, pero al momento de querer entrar al evento que se les asigno, no hacen nada. he intentado con el evento OnInit pero no he logrado nada.

**CODIGO EDITADO**

Creó get y set:

```
public bool AssignClicked
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["AssignClicked"]);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["AssignClicked"] = value;
            }
        }
```

Este es mi código donde genero los botones en `Page_Init`:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssignClicked)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
            var name = Btn_clic.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.CommandArgument = name;

                newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(newButton_Click);


                Botones.Add(newButton);

                GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es donde intento entrar al evento que se les asigna:

```
protected void Assign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssignClicked = true;
        Page_Init(sender, e);
    }
```

Evento `newButton_Click`:

```
protected void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Button Btnclick = (Button)sender;
            var team = Btnclick.Text;
            string name = Btnclick.CommandArgument;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.TEAM == team && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM);
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }
```

Este es el lugar donde se ingresan los botones generados:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" ControlID="Btn_eng">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="tools_info" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width: 450px">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h3 id="title-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp Tools information</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <%--<asp:Button ID="Btn_good" Text="Good condition" CssClass="btn-link" runat="server" />--%>
                                <button id="Btn_good" class="btn-link" onclick='TableGood();'" type="button">Good Condition</button>
                                <asp:Button ID="Btn_bad" Text="Bad condition" CssClass="btn-link" runat="server" OnClientClick="TableBad();" />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="container">
                                <div id="tgood">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="GoodPanel" runat="server">**AQUI SE INSERTAN LOS BOTONES**</asp:Panel>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn_eng" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                                <div id="tbad">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="BadPanel"></asp:Panel>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn_bad" EventName="Click" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn_eng" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Para la edicion de mi codigo, me guie de una  [Pregunta relacionada a mi problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408613/linkbutton-onclick-event-is-not-triggering-for-dynamically-created-buttons-c-sha).

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Preciona F12 y dinos si ves algun error en la consola.

Comment: @EinerSantana hice lo que me indicaste y no, no me marca ningun tipo de error

Comment: quiero creer que newButton_Click existe no?

Comment: @gbianchi asi es, permiteme agregarlo

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Yo diria que los añades demasiado tarde para asignarles eventos de servidor, prueba con Page_PreInit.